# Modal not showing in Vue based on query parameter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, modal-dialog

I have a Vue.js app that shows a modal correctly if I click a button, but I'd like to show it based on a URL parameter. I have an open method for the modal:

```
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    show() {
      console.log("showing modal")
      this.$modal.show("set-game-name");
    },
...
```

and this all works fine from a button in the template:

```
<button @click="show">Click</button>
```

It prints "showing modal" and the modal pops up.

However, what I want to do is set a Vuex store variable, based on the URL search string and show the modal if set. This works fine from this code in App.vue

```
created() {
  if (location.search.match(/walkThrough/) {
    this.$store.dispatch("updateWalkThrough", true)
  }
}
```

This works as expected, the variable gets set. In the modal component's create, I have:

```
created() {
  console.log(this.walkThrough)
  if (this.walkThrough) {
    this.show() // Same show function as above
  }
```

This prints out the correct value for walkThrough and logs "showing modal" correctly as before. However, the modal doesn't appear. No errors are logged in the console... Any ideas? Is there a different life-cycle hook I need to use?

Comment: should probably go in mounted

Answer (score 0):

instead of `create` method try `mounted` method.

The `create` method calls before loading the page and the `mounted` method calls if the page has been loaded.